# Hide 'Related' tab from the Case for interactive Experience form in Dynamics 9.0

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-uci

Is there any way to remove the 'Related' tab from the Case for interactive Experience form? There are no related entities to the form still the related tab is coming up in the form.

Already tried from the customization form.

[image]

Comment: Out of Box I believe this is not possible but maybe someone with more information can add some idea.

Comment: I tried using javascript to hide the tab. In a way that works. But it hides only after full page is loaded. So it is visible that the tab is being hidden after the page is loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide the related tab in UCI by following below steps:

1. Go to the form editor for the entity that you want to hide the related tab
2. Open form properties
3. Click on Display tab
4. Uncheck the checkbox "Show Navigation Items"
5. Now refresh you entity form page to see if the related tab is hidden

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: That does not work in Dynamics 365.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not configurable/customizable as of today, OOB "Related" tab is showing always (without any navaigation entities under that). This is by design today.

Even scripting is not providing a great user experience. This is bothering all our clients, so created an [PowerApps idea](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/PowerApps-Ideas/Auto-hide-the-OOB-quot-Related-quot-tab-instead-of-showing-quot/idi-p/364385).